# Operator name in LL(1) computation

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, terminology, formal-grammars

I'm working from a definition of the LL(1) property of context-free languages in order to build a LL(1)-computer, i.e., a program capable of determining whether a given context-free language is in LL(1).

The definition requires the disjointness of certain sets; each set is defined as an infinite limit, but practically calculated via fixed-point iteration of an inductive, case-based equation.

Present in these equations is the definition of a new operator to simplify the notation (let $\epsilon$ be the empty sequence):

$$\forall S,T : S \oplus T = \begin{cases}
  S & \epsilon \not\in S \\
  (S \setminus \{\epsilon\}) \cup T & \epsilon \in S
\end{cases}$$

I know this operator in latex as `\oplus`. In an attempt to write readable-code, I want to give this operator a name (and endow scala `Set`s with a trait that expresses this name).

Is there a traditional name for this usage of $\oplus$? If so, what is it?

Bonus points: if the name is, e.g., *add*, is there an acceptable word like *addable* with the meaning that two objects—mathematical or code—are capable of being *added*?

Comment: Tagging this was surprisingly difficult; I'd be grateful if someone could suggest appropriate tags to get this to the right audience.

Comment: You'd probably enjoy Parsing Theory by Sippu & Soisalon-Soininen. In section 5.5 (in volume 1), they present a thorough derivation of a relational expression for the LL(1) prediction relation. Together with the earlier discussion of computing relational expressions, you have a complete algorithm not dependent on least fixed point iteration. Hopefully, your library has a copy.

Comment: @rici thanks for the recommendation. Anything on category theory for computer scientists?

Comment: Nope, sorry. My CS presence is actually pretty small. But good luck with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set of values that comes with an "add" operation that is associative is called a [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup).  If it also comes with an element that plays the role of 0 (so that 0 + x = x and x + 0 = x for all x), it is a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid).

In your case, you have a monoid, as $\{\epsilon\}$ plays the role of 0 (it is an identity).

Comment: I saw your update regarding the monoid—had to mentally prove the identity. Will update my own answer accordingly. Funny how these structures seem to arise.

Answer (score 2):

[D.W.'s answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/107433/61762) is excellent, and gave me a rabbit hole to dig through. The operator clearly establishes a magma, being a closed binary operator. I was able to construct a proof<sup>1</sup> that $\oplus$ as defined is associative; thus, the definition gives (at least) a semigroup.

Further, I claim the following: Given any domain (call it the type $A$) and an element $a \in A$, parameterize $\oplus$ on $a$ such that

$$\forall S,T \in \mathcal{P}(A) : S \oplus_a T = \begin{cases}
  S & a \not\in S \\
  (S - \{a\}) \cup T & a \in S
\end{cases}$$

The resulting object $(\mathcal{P}(A), \oplus_a)$ is a semigroup.

I have also shown that $\oplus_a$ is not commutative, for let $X$ be some set not containing $a$ and $Y \neq (X \cup \{a\})$ be a set containing $a$: then $X \oplus_a Y = X$, but $Y \oplus_a X = (Y - \{a\}) \cup X \neq X$.

So the resulting object cannot be an Abelian group.

Proofs remain to be had regarding the <strike>(non)existence of an identity</strike> or the (non)invertibility. If identity can be shown, we have a monoid. If invertibility can be shown, we have an inverse semigroup. If both, then a full group.

The identity element, as pointed out by D.W., is $\Phi = \{a\}$. Put simply:

$$\forall S \in \mathcal{P}(A) : \Phi \oplus_a S = (\Phi - \Phi) \cup S = S$$
$$\forall S \in \mathcal{P}(A) : S \oplus_a \Phi = \begin{cases}
  S & a \not\in S \\
  (S - \Phi) \cup \Phi = S & a \in S
\end{cases} \big\}= S$$

So we have  a monoid.

---

<sup>1</sup> Proof of associativity is sketched as follows: we must show that $\forall X,Y,Z \in \mathcal{P}(A) : (X \oplus Y) \oplus Z = X \oplus (Y \oplus Z)$.

Now we consider that each of these sets has two states: it either contains or does not contain $a$. Because we need three two-bit states to represent the problem space (the set of cases), we have 7 cases, which we represent as a binary tuple $xyz$. If an element is $0$, it indicates that the corresponding set contains $a$ in the equation. If it is a $1$, it indicates that the corresponding set does not contain $a$ in the equation.

Finally, let $X^0$ be the set $X$ containing $a$ for each of our sets, and $X^1$ similarly be the set not containing $a$. Let $XY = X \cup Y$.

A few facts:

- $X^0 \oplus Y^0 = X^1Y^0$
- $X^0 \oplus Y^1 = X^1Y^1$
- $X^1 \oplus Y^0 = X^1 \oplus Y^1 = X^1$
- $X^1Y^1 \oplus Z^0 = X^1Y^1 \oplus Z^1 = X^1Y^1$

The cases are left as an exercise to the reader; they are incredibly straightforward.

*Hint:* $001$ follows from $000$. Similarly, $011$ follows from $010$. Both $101$ and $111$ follow from $100$.